# Displaying first of the year and incrementing each year

Tags: python

Why does pd.date_range display 1/1/1970 when incrementing by day but the end of the year when incrementing by year

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

n = 100
randoms = pd.DataFrame(dict(
  Rand1=np.random.normal(loc=1,scale=2,size=n),
  Rand2=np.random.normal(1,2,size=n),
  Rand3=np.random.normal(1,2,size=n)  
))

randoms['Date'] = pd.date_range(start='1/1/1970', periods=n, freq='y')
print(randoms)
```

here is my output but I need the date to display the first day of the year and not the last day

```
       Rand1     Rand2     Rand3       Date
0   1.139258 -1.390884  2.032142 1970-01-31
1   0.386232  2.029267 -1.499711 1970-02-28
2   3.314543  1.671777 -0.069631 1970-03-31
3  -1.426235  1.543605  1.643718 1970-04-30
4  -2.286934  3.986482  1.763480 1970-05-31
..       ...       ...       ...        ...
95  2.991113  1.723248  1.053139 1977-12-31
96  2.906345  0.268920  4.029668 1978-01-31
97  2.162349  2.251527  3.456534 1978-02-28
98 -2.415481  2.097225 -4.070858 1978-03-31
99  4.142901  1.051146 -3.559649 1978-04-30
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. What do you expect the output to be?

Comment: _I need the date to display the first day of the year and not the last day_ - do you mean the `first day of month` for every month?

Comment: BTW, this output is not the output of the posted code? This output was produces when `freq=m`.

Comment: Please create a [mre]. The code `import pandas as pd; print(pd.date_range(start='1/1/1970', periods=100, freq='y'))` should be sufficient to demonstrate - and it works for me (Pandas 1.3.3)

Answer (score 0):

That's because the `freq=y` means `year end frequency`. If you want `year start frequency`, use `ys` like so:

```
randoms['Date'] = pd.date_range(start='1/1/1970', periods=n, freq='YS')
```

Which produces this:

```
      Rand1     Rand2     Rand3       Date
0 -0.185472  1.079234  3.568975 1970-01-01
1  2.395674  0.506991  1.342406 1971-01-01
2  2.850708  1.185848  4.090613 1972-01-01
3 -0.272404  1.071543  3.011254 1973-01-01
4 -0.116338  0.563471 -0.114609 1974-01-01
```

You can check the whole list of frequency aliases from [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/timeseries.html#timeseries-offset-aliases).